# Unable to send english text using gsm modem with AT commands

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, sms, gsm, at-command

I tried to send a text "alert" but it became "5w", sent out other kind of messages and they all end up being some weird characters like =ìteèNñq¥tΔ6M#ΦReÅZ¡Δf¿£AfåP3TÅbVÉè /&pøo3Λ+XKw6
ΣPΨΓ8FwΘBΩ. I am not sure what i did wrongly can anybody help me with this problem?

```
Public Sub New(ByRef COMMPORT As String)
        'initialize all values
        SMSPort = New SerialPort
        With SMSPort
            .PortName = COMMPORT
            .BaudRate = 115200
            .Parity = Parity.None
            .DataBits = 8
            .StopBits = StopBits.One
            .Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
            .DtrEnable = True
            .RtsEnable = True
            .NewLine = vbCrLf
        End With
    End Sub
    Public Function SendSMS() As Boolean
        If SMSPort.IsOpen = True Then
            'sending AT commands
            SMSPort.WriteLine("AT")
            SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf) 'set command message format to text mode(1)
            SMSPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGS= " & Chr(34) + phonenumber + Chr(34) & vbCrLf)  
            _ContSMS = False
            SMSPort.WriteLine("alert" & vbCrLf & Chr(26)) 'SMS sending

            SMSPort.Close()
        End If
    End Function

    Public Sub Open()
        If Not (SMSPort.IsOpen = True) Then
            SMSPort.Open()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Close()
        If SMSPort.IsOpen = True Then
            SMSPort.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why is COMPORT passed ByRef?

Comment: Have you tried those serial port settings with a terminal program like Tera Term or PuTTy? Garbage on a serial connection is often due to wrong settings.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes i tried on putty and the result is the same weird characters

Comment: @Mary thats the function for declaring the comport/choosing the comport

Comment: I am talking about `Public Sub New(ByRef COMMPORT As String)` Why is that string being passed ByRef? It is not being changed in that Sub.

Comment: @Tim so maybe tweak the settings til you get it working with putty, then write code

Comment: @Tim 9600 is a more likely baud rate, but the correct thing to do would be to look at the specifications for the mystery GSM modem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton tried 9600 but i cannot type anything in putty terminal unless baud rate is 115200 followed this guide but doesn't work for me https://bluocean.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/25000001265-how-to-change-baud-rate-from-115200-to-9600-

Comment: @Tim Then you will have to try all the baud rates. Of course, you should be able to find the correct value in the manual for the GSM modem.